# which event is used to slide finger left and right ward in android?

Tags: android

i am creating image gallery if i click on grid view of images it shows full screen image.

now i want to implement functionality of touch screen or finger sliding left and right ward to change images.

any one guide me which event should i use or whats the procedure

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: I don't think you can control the user's fingers by using events. That would be creepy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using this example we can detect gestures of moving finger left , right , up and downward

http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-gestures.html

Answer (score 2):

You have to implement onTouchEvent and determine when the slide is actually happening. There is no built-in event for it.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this behavior in my application JustPictures, for the exact same purpose. I did it via `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` :

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){...}
```

You can get the X position of the finger with `event.getX()`, and compute the offset from the last time you received the event. You can then update an offset variable that is private to your view, and `postInvalidate()`. Then your `onDraw` method takes care of translating the canvas by the current offset.

Comment: @UMMA: A bit more what? Also, asking for people to reply by e-mail is rude towards the community. Any additions should be added to the post so that other people can learn as well.

Comment: Check this new article on Andrid blog : http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

I think you should find all you need there.

Answer (score 0):

I've used onGesturePerformed callback, but you have to record the gesture pattern using the Emulator, save the pattern on the res and do something like this:
Activity:

```
mLibrary = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
if (!mLibrary.load()) {
 finish();
}           
GestureOverlayView gestures = (GestureOverlayView)   
findViewById(R.id.gestures);
gestures.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
  ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = mLibrary.recognize(gesture);
  if (predictions.size() > 0 && predictions.get(0).score > 1.0) { ... }}
```